# Next-auth - Middleware has no protective effect on my app, I don't know hwy?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I followed the basic setup of next-auth to use in my app, using the Credentials provider.

I have correctly applied the `SessionProvider` to my `_app.tsx`

Next, the way I understood to protect your app easily, would be to simply add a `middleware.ts` to your source folder (same folder as the `pages/` folder , with the following.

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

export const config = { matcher: ["/dashboard"] };
```

How is that that, if I start my program, and go straight to `http://localhost:3000/dashboard`, the page shows properly? even though the logs show the `session.status` unauthenticated? I would expect it to be blocked.

I have not managed in the `/dashboard` page the condition that if `sesssion.status` is unauthorized case. But I would have imagined that the middleware would have taken care of this? Or what's the purpose? What should I expect?

Comment: I did not properly put the `middleware.ts` in the right place. I had mistakenly put it in the `pages` folder, not in the same folder as the `pages`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` to your `.env` file :

```json
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=EXAMPLESECRET
```

also make sure

1. you sign out before testing it because if you rebuild your app that does not sign out the user
2. the middleware file you use had the correct name `middleware` .ts/.js
3. the path you've set in the `matcher` array is the same as the path you want to apply the middleware to.
4. the middleware file is in the source folder

Comment: The secret is well in my .env.local file. I also created a .env and put it in there. I properly signed out, restarted the app. And can still access /dashboard page.

Comment: Ahh...sorry. `middleware`  was IN the `pages`  folder, not in the same src folder as the pages folder. Now it seems to work.

Comment: didn't mentioned that because you said that it is in the source folder lol

Comment: lol sorry. Frustrated since yesterday to try to get this thing working... and it was a simple mistake. I knew where it had to be, I just wasn't seeing it right.

Comment: That happens no problem ^^

Comment: Ok, so now, I can not access any of my pages. Even after successful login, I won't be redirected to the callbackUrl, which is part of the matcher in the middleware.ts...

Comment: matcher  is for define all the pages that you don't want the user to have access untill he logs in if the page url is not included there so the user can have access to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252554/discussion-between-m3-b-and-ahmed-sbai).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another comment - make sure you are signed out. I made so many edits and tried so many things... turns out it was working correctly but my user was signed in.

As soon as i loaded my app in a private browser window the authentication was applying to every page with just this 1 line in the middleware.ts file placed in root directory.

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";
```

Comment: I actually never got it to work on my dev localhost. On my prod and published version, it works fine